# Issue with the JqxGrid using AngularJS

Tags: c#, html, css, angularjs

HTML Code:

```
<table id="demo" style="width:100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Active</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in TitleList">
      <td> {{person.Title}} </td>
      <td><i ng-class="{'fa green fa-check':person.IsActive,'fa red fa-remove':!person.IsActive}"></i></td>
      enter code here </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS Code:

```
$timeout(function () {
  $("#demo").jqxDataTable({
      altRows: true,
      sortable: true,
      columns:[
                { text: 'Title', columngroup: 'Title', datafield: 'Title', align: 'left', width: '100%' },
                { text: 'Status', columngroup: 'IsActive', datafield: 'Active', align: 'left', width: '100%' }
      ]
  });
});
```

But the problem is in the UI class is not applied in the `jqxGrid`. When the put the value `({{person.Title}})` outside the `table` its working. But can anybody please how can work with `table` for `JqXgrid` columns.

Note: I don't want the foreach to be used in `JS`

In UI the font awesome is loaded on page load and after that it is removed.

Please check

[image: screenshot]

I need like this https://snag.gy/tElAHv.jpg, but when i am trying with Angular i class not working.

Thanks

Comment: person object where it is? I mean where your getting, where did you placed in the scope

Comment: In the page load method on success i am filling the ($scope.TitleList = data) and created the object of TitleList  in UI in tbody